# TCP/IP: Нормально ли сперва делать Write, а затем читать ответ через Read, и если нет, то как решить проблему?

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм, сокет, tcp-ip

Недавно написал и запустил клиент-серверную систему. Сама система пока что очень примитивная, но изначально есть сложность - она работает 24/7/366, и притом она в интернете, а не в локальной сети. Поэтому требования к надежности очень жесткие.

На каждое сообщение нужно либо получать ответ от приемника, либо readenBytes = 0, либо Exception который свидетельствует либо о штатном отключении (приемник послал RST), либо об обрыве (выдернули кабель, пропал Wi-Fi и прочая)

Вызовы я использовал блокирующие.

Но реализуя алгоритм, я обратил внимание, что вся его логика сводится вот к этому:

```
try {
tcp.Write(request);
} catch { ... }
try {
var response = tcp.Read();
} catch { ... }
```

Естественно, все в одном потоке: 1 поток на клиенте, и на сервере тоже только 1 поток на 1 клиента.

Чем это плохо?
Если ответ просто задержится по времени - то ничем:
1) выполнился write
2) выполнение дошло до read, read встал в положение WAIT
3) прошло N времени
4) наконец ответ дошел, и тут read считал его и вышел из WAIT

Все нормально.
Но вспомните про возможную потерю кабеля. И представьте такую ситуацию:

0) кабель на месте
1) выполнился write. так как кабель на месте, то пришел ACK и сокет считает, что все в порядке
2) выполнение дошло до read, read встал в положение WAIT
3) и тут произошел обрыв кабеля! Но write-то больше не вызывается поскольку read по-прежнему WAIT, в результате сокет так и не узнает, что произошел обрыв.

Я знаю, что write не блокирует выполнение, и очень мала вероятность, что ACK для write придет раньше чем read встанет в WAIT.
В течение недели ни одного такого случая не было хотя обрывы были каждый день.
Но все-таки, чисто теоретически компьютер может затормозить и система даст сбой.

Как решить данную проблему, если использовать именно блокирующие вызовы, а также не использовать keepalive, а вместо него использовать свою реализацию heartbeat (дело еще и в том, что у меня нет гарантий поддержки keepalive клиентами и серверами)?

Comment: Может поставить таймаут на чтение?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Хм, идея, ведь у меня же есть heartbeat, значит я могу поставить таймаут... Но нормально ли использовать для этого штатную настройку в TCP, нет ли подводных камней, или нужно городить поток, иначе таймаут может где-то (на каких-то версиях винды) не так работать?

Comment: В вашем синхронном варианте напрашивается обычная установка таймаута на прием (`setsockopt(,, SO_RCVTIMEO)`)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а в асинхронном? думаю и такой все же рассмотреть

Comment: В асинхронном тоже таймаут. Это единственный надёжный способ догадаться, что с другой стороной соединения что-то не так. Что синхронно, что асинхронно, tcp может ждать восстановления связи вечно. Есть ещё keepalive, но это вроде не является обязательным. Если другая сторона не поддерживать keepalive, то как бы и нет этого механизма вовсе.

Comment: @Sergey что значит единственный? heartbeatов было бы достаточно, если бы я мог сначала вызвать read и чтобы он встал в WAIT, а после этого вызвать write. но я не вижу способа это сделать кроме городьбы с потоками. его действительно нету? что для синхр., что для асинхр.?

Comment: heartbeat откуда возьмётся? Его же нужно самостоятельно запрограммировать. При этом наличие ответного пакета определяется по тому же самому таймауту. Нет его его допустим в течении 5 сек, значит всё плохо. Так? Спрашивается:  на хрена нужен этот heartbeat, если всё определяет в любом случае таймаут? Кроме как усложнения протокола и соответственно программы ничего хорошего от heartbeat-а Вы не получите.

Comment: @Sergey ну вы прям озадачили. 0_O heartbeat нужен, чтобы знать доступен ли клиент в данный момент времени, не отправляя никакой полезной нагрузки

Comment: Пусть не отправляя полезной и даже бесполезной нагрузки. Но чтобы определить, что другая сторона жива, нужно чтобы поступали какие-то данные (тоже не важно какие полезные или бесполезные) оттуда. Если данных нет, то tcp будет тупо ждать хоть вечно (смотря как настроена система).

Comment: Чем непосредственное получение данных из сокета в асинхронном режиме отличается от того же самого в синхронном? Точно так же не возможно определить, что связь пропала. Если не укажете таймаут, будите вечно ждать когда асинхронная операция чтения вызовет ваш каллбак или, проверяя асинхронный буфер, будите вечно получать "операция не завершена, читайте дальше, может быть когда нибудь что-то вычитаете".